# Как выбрать элемент на сайте WebDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

сайт https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator.
переключилась на фрейм
поля Number of instances и What are these instances for? заполняются без проблем.
а вот дальше идут выпадающие списки и я никак не могу на них кликнуть.

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("select_value_label_51")));
        WebElement field = driver.findElement(By.id("select_value_label_51"));
        field.click();
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("select_option_63")));
        WebElement value = driver.findElement(By.id("select_option_63"));
        value.click();
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как обратиться к ним и выбрать нужный мне параметр?
Я и другие локаторы пробовала, ничего не выходит..

Comment: Вам принципиально кликать на них? Можно послать в них текст для того чтобы был выбран тот или иной элемент.

Comment: это через select?